# What is a good way to carry out a row-wise dot product between a pair of matrices in R?

Tags: r, matrix

I have an `NxK` matrix `x` and another matrix of identical dimensions which contains coefficients for each of the `K` features and each of `N` groups. I would like a `K` vector where the `i`-th entry is the dot product of the `i`-th row in `x` with the `i`-th row of the coefficient matrix. For example if `x` is:

```
x = matrix(rep(1:3,each=2),ncol=2,byrow=TRUE)
```

and the coeff matrix is:

```
coeff = matrix(c(.5,1,0),nrow=3,ncol=2)
```

The result should be the vector `(1,4,0)` because the dot product of `(1,1)` and `(.5,.5)` is `1`, the dot product of `(2,2)` and `(1,1)` is `4` and the dot product of `(3,3)` with `(0,0)` is `0`. I can imagine doing this with a call to sapply on the indices where each iteration is a dot product, but am wondering if there is a better way using a built-in function like sweep or friends..

Comment: Really well-phrased question, this helped me a lot, thanks for posting!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Multiply the two matrix using `*` and then do `rowSums`:

```
rowSums(x * coeff)
[1] 1 4 0
```

Comment: Love this answer